# Having trouble understanding forward slash "/" escape character for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For my job I am having trouble understanding this statement:

```
AND PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%/_UK'
AND PRODUCT_NAME LIKE 'INT/_UK'
```

I don't understand what the forward slash means. I know the "_" and "%" are wildcard operators but how would I read this statement and understand the forward slash?

Many thanks for your help.

Tom

Comment: Do you see any difference in the result if you remove it?

Comment: `/` means forward slash, literally, AFAIK.  To escape the underscore you would need `\_`.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slash is no escape character. You are just matching the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` does support an escape character.  The default is a *back*slash:

```
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%\_UK'
```

You can specify the forward slash:

```
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%/_UK' ESCAPE '/'
```

Your code is finding any string that ends in four characters, a forward slash, any character, and then UK.  So, these would all match:

```
abcd/ UK
abcd/?UK
abcd/_UK
```

These would not match:

```
abcd?UK
abcd/  UK
```